# Could not get the id from the url when switching pages in pagination

Tags: php, html

I'm having trouble getting the id from the URL when i'm switching to another page using the pagination, I need this id from the database to view the contents in the navbar when i switch to another page. When I try to switch to pages the contents in the navbar will not appear. Here is my code

```
    <?php
 
 

    $limit = 5;
     $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
     $start =  ($page - 1) * $limit;


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM invoice LIMIT $start, $limit";
    $result1 = $conn->query("SELECT count(id) AS refNo FROM invoice");
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $custCount = $result1->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $total = $custCount[0]['refNo'];
    $pages = ceil($total / $limit);
    
    $previous = $page - 1;
    $next =   $page + 1;
    $id = $_GET['id2'];


     ?> 


 

    <h3 class="text-center" style="color:white">Student Schedules</h3>
          <label for="course" style="color:white">Invoices And Records<br></label>
      
 

         <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
      <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item">
       <a class="page-link" href="viewUserSchedule.php?id=<?php $id?>&page=<?= $previous; ? 
   

    >">Previous</a></li>
        <?php for($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) : ?>

 
  

      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="viewUserSchedule.php?id=<?php $id? 
  >&page=<?= $i; ?>
        "><?= $i ?></a></li>
        <?php endfor; } ?>
   

 

   

     <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="viewUserSchedule.php?id=<?php $id? 
         >&page=<?= $next; ?>">Next</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your codes, you have simple mistake in your codes.
You are using:

```
<?php $id?>
```

and for other variables like $previous you are using:

```
<?=  $previous; ?>
```

So <?= is shortcode for <?php echo and in printing your $id variable you missed the echo
So, you should use :

```
<?php echo $id?>
```

Or

```
<?= $id?>
```

so try this code, and it would work for you:

```
    <h3 class="text-center" style="color:white">Student Schedules</h3>
<label for="course" style="color:white">Invoices And Records<br></label>


<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="viewUserSchedule.php?id=<?php echo $id?>&page=<?=  $previous; ?>">Previous</a></li>
        <?php for($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) : ?>




      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="viewUserSchedule.php?id=<?php echo $id?>&page=<?= $i; ?>"><?= $i ?></a></li>
        <?php endfor; } ?>


        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="viewUserSchedule.php?id=<?php echo $id?>&page = <?= $next; ?>">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: "_So, you should use : `<?php $id?>`_" That's still wrong

Comment: @brombeer thank you. it was a typo ;). the solution edited

Answer (score 0):

Just change this:

```
<?php $id?>
```

to this:

```
<?= $id ?>
```

or this:

```
<?php echo $id ?>
```